# Hide button on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, hide, information-hiding

This is my site:
http://site9171756.91.webydo.com/?v=1

is there a way I can hide my button on a mobile phone? I wanna code different buttons for a mobile devices. This is my coding for the buttons.

HTML

```
<a href="http://site9171756.91.webydo.com/Info.html" target="page3"
class="Button1" style="position: absolute; left: 60%; top: 400px; z-index:
1000;"  >Bliv forhandler</a>
```

CSS:

```
.Button1 {
font-family: Arial;
color: #FF0000;
font-size: 20px;
background: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
border: solid #FF0000 2px;
text-decoration: none;
} 

.Button1:hover {
  background: #FF7A7A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Regards =)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the button using media queries on mobile

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .Button1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Can find more detail about media queries [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thank you.. very simple ! :)